# Equivalent of logrotate on OSX

Tags: mac-osx, logging, mac-osx-server, logrotate

Is [logrotate](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) hiding somewhere on OSX, or is there an equivalent? It's not in `/usr/sbin`.

Comment: I notice there is newsyslog, but that's not quite the same and requires root.

Comment: Can logrotate be ported, i wonder.

Comment: check /etc/periodic, I believe that log rotation is by default implemented as a set of shell scripts in there.  Also look at newsyslog (/etc/newsyslog.d and man page) for a way to do it based on file size.

Comment: thanks for the tips - there are indeed scripts in /etc/periodic

Comment: @SteveBennett How else are people going to get their "Critic" badges? Some people are only here for the badges and reputation, didn't you know.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Based on Brian Armstrong's answer, here's something with a little more explanation and a correction. This handles the log created by postgres on OSX installed by Homebrew. Located at `/etc/newsyslog.d/postgresql.conf`:

```
# logfilename                           [owner:group]      mode count size(KB)  when  flags [/pid_file]                            [sig_num]
/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.log  :                  600  2     2048      *     J     /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
```

This will rotate the log file when it reaches 2MB in size, keep 2 archives (for a total of 6MB storage used), and bzip2-compress the archives. It will notify the postgres process to reopen the log files once rotated, which is necessary to get new log entries and to actually free the disk space without restarting the machine.

Important to note that size is in KB, not bytes.

You can test the config file (without affecting any files) using `sudo newsyslog -nvv`.

newsyslog documentation is located here: http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?newsyslog.conf(5).
Also used: http://www.redelijkheid.com/blog/2011/3/28/adding-custom-logfile-to-os-x-server-log-rotation.html

Comment: I just spent a good 20 minutes trying to figure out what actually runs `newsyslog` on modern macOS. I'll append the answer here, in case it's of use to anyone:  As can be expected, `newsyslog` execution is controlled by `launchd(8)`. The property list is located (on 10.15.3) at `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.newsyslog.plist`.

Answer (score 27):

OS X has several ways to rotate/expire/etc its logs, depending on the type of log in question:

1. For regular log files (i.e. text files that are continuously appended to), [newsyslog](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/newsyslog.8.html) can rotate them based on size or time, although it doesn't seem to have as many options as `logrotate`.  It's configured by `/etc/newsyslog.conf` and `/etc/newsyslog.d/*` (generally, you should add files to `/etc/newsyslog.d/` to add logs to its management list).
2. OS X's syslog system is migrating from this plain-text format to  database format, mainly in `/var/log/asl/`. I don't entirely understand this system yet, but this database seems to be purged by [aslmanager](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/aslmanager.8.html), which is configured by `/etc/asl.conf`.
3. For directories that have individual log "entries" added as separate files (mainly `/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/`), the files get purged by `/etc/periodic/daily/100.clean-logs`.  Its policies (which directories to scan & how long to leave files) are configured in `/etc/defaults/periodic.conf`, but if you want to override/change them you should create `/etc/periodic.conf.local` and put your customizations there.

If what you want to rotate doesn't fit any of these models, you can add your own scripts to `/etc/periodic/daily/` (which'll be run every morning at 3:15am), `/etc/periodic/weekly/` (every saturday morning at 3:15am), or `/etc/periodic/monthly/` (first of every month at 5:30am).

Answer (score 24):

You can get logrotate via Homebrew.  Here are my notes from setting this up.

### Install

`brew install logrotate`

### Configure log rotation

Log rotation config files are in `/usr/local/etc/logrotate.d/`

Edit config file.  E.g. I wanted to rotate some "/var/log/tend_*.log" files I introduced:

`sudo vi /usr/local/etc/logrotate.d/tend.conf`

Contents:

`/var/log/tend_*.log {
  daily
  copytruncate
  rotate 3
  size 10M
  compress
}`

### Test it out

`sudo  logrotate -v -f /usr/local/etc/logrotate.d`

### Start service

`sudo brew services start logrotate`

### Restart service

`sudo brew services restart logrotate`

Comment: Thank you. For those used to logrotate, this is the best answer.

Comment: Agreed w/previous commenter - thank you, from one old sysadmin to another, this is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: on latest macOs Ventura, After installing logrotate via homebrew it is not available on cmd. Add binary to env variables from this path /opt/homebrew/opt/logrotate/sbin/logrotate

Answer (score 14):

`newsyslog` runs automatically on OSX, I use a config file like this in `/etc/newsyslog.d/rails_apps.conf` to keep my dev log files trimmed to 5MB

```
# logfilename                           [owner:group]   mode count size     when  flags [/pid_file] [sig_num]
/Users/barmstrong/code/**/log/*.log                     666  0     5242880  *     G
```

Comment: size is in K, and a ":" is required for owner:group even if they're blank

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it:

http://blog.cantremember.com/logrotate-mac-os-launch-daemon-with-legacy-macport/